# Locale compilation fails because fields are not defined

Tags: locale, amazon-ec2

If i `git push` to a Bitbucket repository, I get the following warnings:

```
Counting objects: 4, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 262 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
remote: perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
remote:         LANGUAGE = (unset),
remote:         LC_ALL = (unset),
remote:         LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
remote:         LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
remote:     are supported and installed on your system.
remote: perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
remote: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
remote: perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
remote:         LANGUAGE = (unset),
remote:         LC_ALL = (unset),
remote:         LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
remote:         LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
remote:     are supported and installed on your system.
remote: perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I tried to compile/generate the missing locale with

```
sudo localedef -v -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

but it didn't work out and the following output is created:

```
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:7: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:8: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:9: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:11: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:14: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:15: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:16: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:17: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:19: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:20: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:21: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:22: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:23: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:24: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:25: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:26: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:27: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:28: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:29: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:34: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:50: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n:1425: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n:1674: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n:1719: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/i18n:1756: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:53: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:59: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_GB:152: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US:40: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1:3: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:10: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:11: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:12: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:13: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:14: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:15: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:16: non-symbolic character value should not be used
/usr/share/i18n/locales/translit_neutral:17: non-symbolic character value should not be used
LC_NAME: field `name_gen' not defined
LC_IDENTIFICATION: field `audience' not defined
LC_IDENTIFICATION: field `application' not defined
LC_IDENTIFICATION: field `abbreviation' not defined
LC_IDENTIFICATION: no identification for category `LC_MEASUREMENT'
no output file produced because warnings were issued
```

Bitbucket runs on an Amazon AMI Linux instance.

What can I do?